# setSize, is changing the location of a JLabel

Tags: java, jframe, location, resize, jlabel

So I have run into a issue in my jLabel. setSize for some reason is changing the location. I have no idea what's going on. I want to make my image bigger:

```
public void tuesdayOperator() {
    ErrorOperator errorOperator = new ErrorOperator();

    tuesdayButton.addActionListener(e -> {
        try {
            setPage2ButtonsInvisible();
            jButtonRemoveEvent();
            //tuesdayBackground.setBounds(-500, -300, 1920, 1080);
            tuesdayBackground.setSize(1920, 2080);
            tuesdayBackground.setLocation(-500, -600);

            jPanel.add(tuesdayBackground);
            tuesdayBackground.setLayout(null);

            jPanel.setBackground(Color.white);
            System.out.println("Tuesday Exercise" + Message.success);
        }catch (Exception exception) {

            errorOperator.emergencyEvent();
        }
    });
}
```

I have tried using `setPreferredSize`

but it has not worked. in reference, here's is the code with `setPreferredSize` . here is the code:

```
public void tuesdayOperator() {
    ErrorOperator errorOperator = new ErrorOperator();

    tuesdayButton.addActionListener(e -> {
        try {
            setPage2ButtonsInvisible();
            jButtonRemoveEvent();
            tuesdayBackground.setPrefferredSize(new Dimension(1920, 1080));

            jPanel.add(tuesdayBackground);
            tuesdayBackground.setLayout(null);

            jPanel.setBackground(Color.white);
            System.out.println("Tuesday Exercise" + Message.success);
        }catch (Exception exception) {

            errorOperator.emergencyEvent();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include code as text, not as images. Images are hard to read, cannot be copied into an editor, and prevent sight impaired users from helping you.

Comment: I see that you’re adding tuesdayBackground to jPanel.  What is the layout of jPanel?

Comment: Yes Thank you for replying sorry for the 6 day late reply, My JPanel's Layout is null. It should of worked since ive done this 2 times before this but i don't know.

Comment: setLayout(null) is something you are not supposed to do.  If you just want tuesdayBackground to take up all the space in jPanel, use `jPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout())`.  It’s much easier to let a layout set position and size correctly, than to try to manage it yourself.

Comment: Thanks Alot , that worked never thought of that.